# Azure App Service Monitoring Logs mostly not working

Tags: azure, logging

I have a simple .NET Core WebApi published to Azure as an App Service. It works fine but I'm having trouble getting Monitoring Logs.

- Log Stream works fine, can tail and watch stdout logs flowing through.
- Added Diagnostic Setting to collect "allLogs" with destinations set to "Send to Log Analytics workspace" and "Archive to storage account"
- Weirdly enough 8 results do show up (from a few hours ago). But nothing new (again I can watch the logs coming in through Log Stream).

[image]

I guess my question is what can I look into to figure out why no new entries are showing up anymore?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was to do with my "Application Insights" resource. It wasn't pointing to the correct "Log Analytics Workspace"? The problem seems resolved now.